Cannot Test Subscriptions in Sandbox Before App Review Approval
Question:
I am currently implementing a subscription-based feature in my app and facing a circular issue with the App Store review and Sandbox testing. Here is the situation:

I created a subscription in App Store Connect and configured its metadata, display name, and descriptions correctly.
The subscription status is currently "Waiting for Review".
To test the subscription in the Sandbox environment, I need it to be approved and in a "Ready for Sale" state. However, for it to be approved, it requires my app to include a working subscription page.
On the other hand, to display a functional subscription page in the app, I need to validate the subscription in the Sandbox environment first.

This creates a circular dependency where I cannot test the subscription without it being approved, and I cannot include it in the app for review without testing it.
Steps I have taken so far:
Configured the subscription correctly in App Store Connect.
I added localization, descriptions, and review information for the subscription. I ensured that the metadata matches with my subscription setup in Adapty (3rd-party tool for subscriptions).
Submitted an app version for review:
I set "Version Release" to Manually release this version.
I added the subscription to the app version.
I included a static Premium Subscription page in my app to simulate the subscription process.
Review Outcome:
The app was rejected with the following error:
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs which create a poor user experience. Specifically, the app displays an error message when we attempt to purchase a subscription.
Review device details:
Next Steps:
When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.
My Questions:

Breaking the Cycle: Is there a recommended approach to break this circular issue and allow testing in the Sandbox environment before review approval?

Submission Approach: Should I submit the subscription for review without a fully functional subscription page in the app and explain the situation to the App Review team?

Server Validation Issue: How can I resolve the server receipt validation issue during review testing when the app is not yet live?

Alternative Methods: Are there alternative ways to validate the subscription setup before moving to production?


I’d appreciate any guidance on how to proceed or best practices to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

See "pre launch testing" https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/engineering/the-ultimate-guide-to-subscription-testing-on-ios/

Thanks, i am trying right now, i hope it works.

Unfortunately, the pre-launch testing part did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

So your in app purchases are now approved and you have a build pending developer release?

Not yet. My in-app purchases are currently 'Pending Review' and my build is also awaiting review. How do I create a build just for in-app purchases? I get rejections every time I submit my app for review

You need to submit your in app purchases along with your app and get them all reviewed at the same time. You can set the build to manual release. Once everything is approved you can test with TestFlight or promo codes and release once you are happy.  This is what the revenuecat page was explaining

The main issue here is that I haven't been able to get my subscriptions through the review process yet. Without having them approved, I can't test them in Sandbox or TestFlight environments, which makes it impossible to observe whether they are working correctly. This creates a frustrating cycle where I can't verify my setup without approval, and I can't get approval without verifying my setup.

Why are they rejecting your subscriptions? They need to be submitted at the same time as the app that uses them.  You don't need any simulated subscription pages.

The rejection is due to my app displaying an error message when attempting to purchase the subscription. They mentioned that the app is not handling the receipt validation properly. The issue is that I can't fully implement and test the subscription logic in the app because the subscriptions are still in 'Waiting for Review' status, and I can't test them in the Sandbox environment until they are approved. In short, the subscription page in my app is not working, so they are rejecting it

The message about receipt validation is just a generic message that they always send. Receipt validation is deprecated. You should use StoreKit 2 if possible. Does an Xcode build work without a StoreKit configuration? That should work without the in app purchases needing to be approved.  If it doesn't then you need to work out why it isn't working.

I actually tested my subscription page using StoreKit configurations, and it was working fine during testing. I submitted the app with the same configuration for review, but it still got rejected. It seems like even though StoreKit configurations simulate the subscriptions, the App Review process still requires the actual in-app purchases to be approved and functional and I don't know how to get through this process, I wish people would share how they get through this

StoreKit configurations are only for testing locally. Remove the StoreKit configuration and ensure an Xcode build lets you subscribe with a sandbox user. This does not require your subscription products to be approved. Once an Xcode build is working without a StoreKit configuration you are ready to submit your app and the subscription products for review.

So, you're saying that if I test my subscriptions using StoreKit configurations and see them working, then deactivate the StoreKit configuration before submitting for review, even if it doesn't work in the sandbox environment for me, it will still work for Apple reviewers, and my app will pass the review. Is that correct?

After removing the StoreKit configuration, my Xcode build with a sandbox user does not allow me to test subscriptions because the subscriptions are still in the 'Waiting for Review' state.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
